Daisy chaining AWS CloudFront Distributions weird "Via" behavior
I am trying to daisy chain CloudFront distributions and, for reasons I want to find out about in this thread, I am running into the "not more than TWO chained distributions"-limit and a resulting HTTP 403 response. I heard about CloudFront chaining and the limit thereof in another SO post (which has a pretty duplicate version of its own, don't be confused as I was...)
This is our setup: Since our product offers a whitelabel solution with literally thousands of customer domains and the associated certificates, we have a lot of cloudfront distributions (at least one for each domain, plus subdomains),  kind of as a workaround to manage all the certificates. (In the long run, this solution might be questioned as well, but this would be a big task of its own) Their origins are pointing to the app's loadbalancer.
This is what I want to achieve: To be able to centralize any configuration of CDN-related tasks I would like to make these distributions point to another (new, single) distribution instead of our app's loadbalancer so that any configuration (change of origin/caching/...) can be made on this one distribution, instead of writing scripts to run through all of the 1000+ CF distributions.
The problem:
As pointed out in the linked SO post, CloudFront will only allow the chaining of TWO distributions. A THIRD will result in an HTTP 403 response from CF. My problem is that, although my solution only involves the chaining of TWO instances, I get exactly this behavior.
My debugging research:
The linked SO post suggests the use of curl -v domain.com to see the number of CF distributions in the 'Via:' headers. These are the results (domains of case 1 and 3 are customer domains pointing to CF configured in Route53, case 2 is the distribution's default domain) :

old-customer-domain-as-is.com: 1 CF-Via header
new-centralized-proxy-cf-domain-abc123faba.cloudfront.net: 1 CF-Via header
domain-now-pointing-to-proxy-cf-domain-abc123faba-customer.com: 3 CF-Via headers (HTTP 403)

I could not find out what actual CF instances were concerned since the domains referenced in the via headers seem to be volatile/generated on the fly and hashed.
My question:
Do you have any tips about how to further debug this? Or can you shed any more light about how CF distributions work, because obviously my concept about them is wrong: Take two CF distros with the origin at my LB, you get ONE hop via CF each, chain them together, you get THREE hops. Where's my thinking wrong in expecting chaining them should make only TWO hops? THX!
